# Proper use of CD4504BE Level Shifter IC for SPI

Tags: spi, level-shifting, 5v, texas-instruments, 3.3v

CD4504BE Datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4504b.pdf

I've been searching all over the web for a proper example of the use of this IC, but I haven't found anything. My basic application is to shift the 5V SPI signals from ATmega328P (Master) to the 3.3V ESP8266 (Slave).

The below diagram shows how I believe it should be connected:

[image: CD4504BE Connections]

Questions:

1. Are these connections correct? If not, how should these be connected?
2. Regarding the MISO line, I show it as connected directly from ESP8266 to ATmega328P. This works, but ideally I would like to shift this 3.3V signal up to 5V. Is this possible with a single IC? My assumption is no, I would need a second CD4504BE. If it is possible, how should it be connected?

Comment: Can I suggest using a more modern part? You'll find that there are numerous bidirectional, 4-bit level shifters that very neatly solve your problem. For instance, the [TI TXS0104](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0104e.pdf).

Comment: It is a good suggestion, as I mentioned in my other comment the reason I selected the CD4504BE was because it was the lowest cost option available in a DIP package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are these connections correct? If not, how should these be connected?

**Yes**. Except that SELECT pin shall be connected to Ground.

> I would like to shift this 3.3V signal up to 5V. Is this possible
>   with a single IC? My assumption is no

You are **right**.

> I would need a second CD4504BE. If it is possible, how should it be
>   connected?

You can opt. for second IC, you have to swap VDD and VCC connection.
But, If you can use single IC solution, you can find many better solutions. As mentioned in the comment the 4 bit bidirectional level translator, [TXS0104E](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0104e.pdf),  can do the job of both ICs.

Here is the block diagram with the voltage rating:
ESP device will be the system controller(block to the left) and Arduino will be the system (block in the right).  Voltage ratings suggest that, it meets your expectation.

[image]

**for MISO line**
you can also consider this and works for sure.

```
Low Side - ESP  
High Side - Arduino
```

[image]

The above circuit can be simply repeated thrice and you do not need the level shifter IC at all.   You just have to swap Low side and High side for MOSI, CS and CLK pins.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The reason I selected the CD4504BE was because it was the lowest cost option available in a DIP package. Appreciate the info on the TXS0104E, it certainly is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

On page one, when SELECT is pulled down, it does CMOS to CMOS conversion. Since the Arduino and the ESP8266 are both CMOS uC, you should pull the SELECT pin down. Vss goes to ground.

You will need 2 of these ICs. For going from Arduino to ESP8266:

Vdd as shown in the table in page 2 should be the voltage level of the ESP8266 (3.3V) and Vcc Arduino 5V.

For ESP8266 to Arduino:

Vdd should be 5V and Vcc 3.3V.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information, I will connect it accordingly and add a second IC if required.